# Novy-Marx Profitability "Excess" returns - What does Excess mean here?

Tags: returns, factor-models, factor-investing

I am reading Novy-Marx's paper titled "The other side of value: The gross profitability premium".

Throughout the paper, he mentions excess returns in several tables, but I cannot find any mention of what this is in "excess" too. Just by eyeballing the numbers, it seems like it's in excess to a T-bill or similar but I can't exactly be sure. I've searched throughout the paper and can't find an answer.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAQTc.jpg) is an example.

Comment: As you say, it seems safe to assume that Novy-Marx uses the one-month Treasury bill rate to correct for funding costs. That's the usual risk-free rate you find on [Ken French's website](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html).

Comment: Anything Novy-Marx does not describe, you can assume it is done "as in Fama French".